# Marcador de puntos en Unity

Tags: unity, unity2d

Estoy creando mi primer proyecto en Unity, un prototipo de un videojuego utilizando C#. Ya está casi listo pero solo me falta el marcador de puntos. De momento he hecho esto:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Puntuacion : MonoBehaviour {
public float TiempoJugando = 0;
public int Tiempo;
public TextMesh marcador;



void Start()
{
    Tiempo = 0;   
}
void Update ()
{
    TiempoJugando = Time.time;
    Tiempo = (int)TiempoJugando;
    Debug.Log(Tiempo);
    marcador.text = Tiempo.ToString();
}
}
```

El problema es que cuando el personaje muere esto sigue activo y si pulsas para volver a jugar sigue contando como si nunca hubiese acabdo la partida. ¿Alguien sabe como solucionarlo?
¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Cuando el personaje muere, ¿se reinicia la escena o se traslada a un punto que has programado? Con la info que das, te diría que "reiniciaras" el tiempo desde el trozo de código donde muere tu personaje. Hay muchas formas de hacerlo y depende mucho de la forma de tu código y del montaje del juego.

Comment: Cuando muere se carga una escena. Entonces hay un botón para volver a cargar la escena del juego. Pero para reiniciar el tiempo tendria que poner el script de puntuacion dentro del que controla la muerte del personaje, no?

Comment: Al final he conseguido arreglarlo, ¡muchas gracias igualmente!

Answer (score 0):

Para esto necesitas hacer una condición.
Es decir, que el contador se ejecute mientras el personaje esta vivo.

```
void Update ()
{
    if(!PlayerState.die && GameManager.inGame) //Enum que define un estado
    {
      TiempoJugando = Time.time;
      Tiempo = (int)TiempoJugando;
      Debug.Log(Tiempo);
      marcador.text = Tiempo.ToString();
    }
}
```

En este ejemplo coloque como condición un estado de juego, en el que le digo que el personaje no esta muerto(esta vivo), y el estado de el juego esta en InGame(Esta jugandose).

Ya teniendo esto en cuenta puedes agregar otra condición, para cuando el personaje muera poder guardar el puntaje con el que quedo, y reiniciar al momento de reiniciar la partida.

En resumen.
Una solución seria decir que la variable TiempoJugando, solo sera igual al Time.time si el personaje esta vivo y/o esta jugando.

Answer (score 0):

Para reiniciar el marcador puedes crear un método sencillo así tipo:

```
RestartMarcador()
{
   TiempoJugando = 0; // Time.time = 0;
}
```

Cuando maten al personaje o salgas del juego llamar al método

```
if(Player.die && GameManager.GameOver || GameManager.BackToMenu)
{
   RestartMarcador();
}
```

Comment: quizas eso deberia hacerse al iniciar el juego. Lo normal suele ser, si el personaje muere, mostrar el tiempo que ha estado jugando. si se hace eso cuando muere, el valor pasa a ser 0 y se pierde ese tiempo.